# gz marker color Gazebo

Tags: gazebo, ros2

Using the following command, I can show a marker in Gazebo:

```
gz marker -m 'action: ADD_MODIFY, type: SPHERE, id: 9, scale: {x: 0.2, y: 0.4, z: 1.2}, pose: {position: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}'
```

Question: how to specify the color? The

```
gz marker -m 'action: ADD_MODIFY, type: SPHERE, id: 9, scale: {x: 0.2, y: 0.4, z: 1.2}, pose: {position: {x: 0.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}, color: {r: 0.0, g: 1.0, b: 0.0, a: 1.0}'
```

doesn't work (error)

Please help.

Also, is there a way to issue a command for a MarkerArray? Or any Python code sample on how to show MarkerArray in Gazebo? Because using command line is... ugly.

Comment: That works, but ignores color (always white):

gz marker -m 'action: ADD_MODIFY, type: SPHERE, scale: {x: 0.2, y: 0.4, z: 1.2}, pose: {position: {x: 3.0, y: 0.0, z: 0.0}}, material: {ambient: {r: 1.0, g: 0.0, b: 0.0}, diffuse: {r: 1.0, g: 0.0, b: 0.0}, emissive: {r: 1.0, g: 0.0, b: 0.0}, specular: {r: 0.0, g: 0.0, b: 0.0}}'